# Links to CSS files with emptied divs

Tags: php, jquery, css

Depending on selections made by the user 1 of a number of php scripts are added to my page via jquery. To do this it adds it's contents to an existing div.
Each of these php come with a link tag adding a CSS file.

My question is, if I empty that div with jquery will the CSS file's effect on the page be removed too? Will any elements then effected by this CSS file revert to their original style?
I ask because this div can be filled and emptied any number of times and the CSS will clash if it remains. And because uploading it to where it is tested is time consuming, so I don't want to attempt something that definitely won't work.

Comment: It depends on your code. Post it.

Comment: css is persistent unless new css is brought in with the ajax response, also you can change/add css with jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the link tag that points to a css file, the css rules contained in the files will be removed with it, so if you empty the `DIV`, the css rules that were contained in the div will be removed.

Comment: Thats what I'm hoping for

Comment: Do as i do when i have css doubts: open the developer console and try in it. For example i deleted a css link and all the styles were removed, so now i'm sure that my answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
I ask because this div can be filled and emptied any 
number of times and the CSS will clash if it remains
```

What I would do (with jQuery) is add/remove the class(es) that clash with the CSS depending if the `DIV` is empty or not, something like :

```
function myToggle() {
    if (!$.trim($("#myDiv").html()).length) {
        return 'green'; // returns a specif class when empty (can be fake with no effect)
    } else {
        return 'red'; // add class when is filled
    }
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Zatr3/)**

That would be simpler than adding/removing CSS files

Comment: I see what you mean, but I'd be adding and removing so many classes, and different classes depending on the PHP script thats added in.  You see this CSS page is for IE only.  I cheated for other browsers by embedding the CSS.  (Trying to keep time down to a minimum